# Codeigniter Unlink doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete an image before deleting an entry so I did this

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('info', array("id" => $info_id));
        $results = $query->result_array();
        echo base_url().'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image'];die();
        unlink(base_url().'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
```

But the file is still there. It doesn't unlink. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to unlink a file. You should try use FCPATH

```
unlink(FCPATH .'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
```

path functions definitions

```
EXT: The PHP file extension
FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)
SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)
BASEPATH: Path to the system folder
APPPATH: The path to the "application" folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
unlink('theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
```

Instead of

```
unlink(base_url().'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First remove `die()` it terminates execution of program.Then try

```
        $query = $this->db->get_where('info', array("id" => $info_id));
        $results = $query->result_array();
        echo base_url().'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image'];
        unlink(base_url().'theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out by this way. Make sure the image file is reachable with the path from the location you execute the PHP script. I'm using **realpath()** to get the file location.

```
$images_location = realpath('theme/transport/images/services/thumbs/' . $results[0]['image']);
if (file_exists($images_location))
{
   unlink($images_location);
}
```

Please let me know if there any problem.